# how to get value from text using regex

Tags: java, regex

iam trying to get work experience from resume, below code works fine if the text is 2 years 7 months
but it does not work with the text  2.7 years.. i just want to get the code if the text would be in both patterns.

```
 String rx = "\\d+\\s+years?\\s+(?:and\\s*)?\\d+\\s+months?|\\d+\\s+(?:months?|years?)";
    Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(rx);
    Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(text);
    while (m.find())
    {System.out.println(m.group(0));}
```

Comment: `(\d+\s+years?\s+(?:and\s*)?\d+\s+months?|\d+\s+(?:months?|years?))|([\d\.]+ year(s)?)` try this, and escape the `\` properly.. hope helps, [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/bf83Zt/1)

Comment: Use `"\\d*\\.?\\d+\\s+years?\\s+(?:and\\s*)?\\d+\\s+months?|\\d*\\.?\\d+\\s+(?:months?|years?)"`

Comment: tried.. but showing error Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )